# Disable Validation Rule with Apex Code

Tags: apex, validation

Is there a way to disable Validation Rule with Apex Code? I need disable a managed Validation Rule in all customer orgs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is common practice to have a boolean flag (say ByPass_VR__c), which can be set via Apex Code to skip it. Unless there is such a provision in this validation rule, you cant temporarily disable it via Apex code.

The only 'work around' is to set field values such that the error formula doesn't evaluate to true.

eg

```
AND(
NOT(ByPass_VR__C),
...
```

Comment: Exactly as @techtrekker said, you probably won't be able to do this since it is a managed validation rule.

Comment: This is correct. But I would put the Flag inside Custom Settings → this way no metter how many VR we have inside the org I can stop them in one place.